# How do you know the search query if the search term is in the middle of the website URL?

Tags: html

I'm wondering what **action url** and **name term** I'm suppose to use if the search term is in the middle of the URL?

For example, the HTML code below allows me to input text and when I press enter or the button, it automatically sends me to the website with the search term already entered.

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search?q=goog">
   <input id="Google" type="text" name="q">
   <button>Search on Google</button>
</form>
```

But I don't get what use if it's an URL like this: [https://youglish.com/pronounce/朋友/chinese](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B/chinese)

I tried this and I'm only sent to the Chinese site, but the search term wasn't searched

```
<form action="https://youglish.com/pronounce/../chinese">
    <input id="Youglish" type="text" name="pronounce">
    <button>Search on Youglish</button>
</form>
```

Or something like in Google images....

https://www.google.com/search?q=testing&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=657&ei=IKIXZIrwH-bF0PEP5paEwA4&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAZBewMDMUyk_z3qZEoFpdrb-I429k6qMC&ved=0ahUKEwiKgPPsmen9AhXmIjQIHWYLAegQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=testing&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyCAgAEIAEELEDMggIABCABBCxAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyCAgAEIAEELEDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgARQKFjuBWCHB2gAcAB4AoABqwOIAe0JkgEJMC4xLjEuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWewAQA&sclient=img

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search?q=..=img">
        <input id="Google Images" type="text" name="q=..=img">
        <button>Search on Google Images</button>
</form>
```

It just takes me to the Google Images website, and not with the search term entered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in this example:

```
https://youglish.com/pronounce/../chinese
```

You meant to add the search term to where the `...` is, the short answer is that you can't do this with just HTML, you need Javascript as well.

The third example should just work, because it does use `?q=`. Using HTML forms query parameters get added to the URL after the `?`, and the order generally doesn't matter.

The google example has a bunch of other parameters that you can individually add to your form with `<input type="hidden">` for each parameter, however for google specifically you can also ignore all those.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work how you think it works.

Your form submission is creating an [HTTP GET request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) and [constructing GET parameters from your form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data). If you type `fox` into the field named `q`, you will get `?q=fox`. If there is a second field named `x` with value `y`, you get `?q=fox&x=y`.

With Google image search, the solution is simply to add a second, hidden field that will cause `&tbm=isch` to be appended to the URL string:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search">
    <input id="Google Images" type="text" name="q">
    <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">
    <button>Search on Google Images</button>
</form>
```

But all of this only works because Google uses GET parameters.

> But I don't get what use if it's an URL like this: [https://youglish.com/pronounce/朋友/chinese](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B/chinese)

Can't be done with pure HTML, you need JavaScript. Something like:

```html
<script>
function searchOnYouglish()
{
    let token = document.getElementById('Youglish').value;
    location.href = `https://youglish.com/pronounce/${token}/chinese`;
    return false; // Prevent default form submission
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return searchOnYouglish()">
    <input id="Youglish" type="text" name="pronounce">
    <button>Search on Youglish</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that with just an HTML form, because when you send the form, the inputs values are added to the action url so in your example:

```
<form action="https://youglish.com/pronounce/../chinese">
    <input id="Youglish" type="text" name="pronounce">
    <button>Search on Youglish</button>
</form>
```

The resulting url would be:

```
https://youglish.com/pronounce/../chinese?pronounce=inputValue
```

and checking the chinese browser, the url you need is:

```
https://youglish.com/pronounce/inputValue/chinese
```

So you can use javaScript to prevent the form event and then create the url and open it as you wish.
Here is the documentation of Event.preventDefault(), it contains some examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault